# SQL Server - Select with Group By together Raw_Number

Tags: t-sql, select, grouping, window-functions, row-number

I'm using SQL Server 2000 (80). So, it's not possible to use the LAG function.

I have a code a data set with four columns:

```
Purchase_Date

Facility_no

Seller_id

Sale_id
```

I need to identify missing Sale_ids. So every sale_id is a 100% sequential, so the should not be any gaps in order.

This code works for a specific date and store if specified. But i need to work on entire data set looping looping through every facility_id and every seller_id for ever purchase_date

```
declare @MAXCOUNT int

set @MAXCOUNT = 
(
    select MAX(Sale_Id) 
    from #table 
    where
        Facility_no in (124) and
        Purchase_date = '2/7/2020'
        and Seller_id = 1
)

;WITH TRX_COUNT AS
(
SELECT 1 AS Number
union all
select Number + 1 from TRX_COUNT
where Number < @MAXCOUNT
)
select * from TRX_COUNT 
where 
Number NOT IN 
(
    select Sale_Id
    from #table 
    where
    Facility_no in (124) 
    and Purchase_Date = '2/7/2020' 
    and seller_id = 1
)   
    order by Number
    OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
```

****My Dataset****

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one worked out

```
; WITH cte_Rn AS (
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Facility_no, Purchase_Date, Seller_id ORDER BY Purchase_Date) AS [Rn_Num] 
FROM (
        SELECT 
            Facility_no,
            Purchase_Date,
            Seller_id,
            Sale_id
        FROM  MyTable WITH (NOLOCK)
    ) a
)
, cte_Rn_0 as (
SELECT 
    Facility_no,
    Purchase_Date,
    Seller_id,
    Sale_id, 
--  [Rn_Num] AS 'Skipped Sale'
--  , case when Sale_id = 0 Then [Rn_Num] - 1 Else [Rn_Num] End AS 'Skipped Sale for 0'
    , [Rn_Num] - 1 AS 'Skipped Sale for 0'
FROM cte_Rn a
)
SELECT 
    Facility_no,
    Purchase_Date,
    Seller_id,
    Sale_id, 
--  [Skipped Sale],
    [Skipped Sale for 0]
FROM cte_Rn_0 a
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
        (  
            select * from cte_Rn_0 b 
            where b.Sale_id = a.[Skipped Sale for 0]
            and a.Facility_no = b.Facility_no 
            and a.Purchase_Date = b.Purchase_Date 
            and a.Seller_id = b.Seller_id
        )
--ORDER BY Purchase_Date ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

This column:

```
case when 
Sale_Id=0 or 1=Sale_Id-LAG(Sale_Id) over (partition by Facility_no, Purchase_Date, Seller_id)
then 'OK' else 'Previous Missing' end
```

will tell you which Seller_Ids have some sale missing. If you want to go a step further and have exactly your desired output, then filter out and distinct the 'Previous Missing' ones, and join with a tally table `on not exists`.

Edit: OP mentions in comments they can't use LAG(). My suggestion, then, would be:

- Make a temp table that that has the max(sale_id) group by facility/seller_id
- Then you can get your missing results by this pseudocode query:

```
    Select ...
    from temptable t
    inner join tally N on t.maxsale <=N.num
    where not exists( select ... from sourcetable s where s.facility=t.facility and s.seller=t.seller and s.sale=N.num)


> because the only way to "construct" nonexisting combinations is to construct them all and just remove the existing ones.
```

Comment: Hi @George, I cannot use the LAG function, my Database version is compatibility with SQL server 2000 (80). I've updated the code in my question. It get me close to what i need. could you look at it?

Comment: In you Join what do you mean by N.num ?

Comment: N is a tally table. A tally table just has numbers from 1 to let's say 1000. You need it to create every possible sale id, then you remove the existing through the not exists, and you get the missing ones.

Comment: I'm kind of lost. I have generated the temp table (called tally) that contains every possible sale_id based on: max(sale_id) from source_table group by Facility_id, Date, Seller_id. Then I inner join it to the source based on tally N on t.maxsale <=N.num.

Comment: So I added a new code that generates to data sets, actual max(sale_id) grouped by  Facility_id, Date, Seller_id and second dataset that generates every possible sale id. But it fails to generate the second data set with the error GROUP BY, HAVING, or aggregate functions are not allowed in the recursive part of a recursive common table expression 'All_PossibleSale_ids'.

Comment: I would greatly appreciate if could you explicitly type the solution out using the four columns I've listed out in my question above.